# WaitForElement does not work in the PageObject

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, pageobjects

The problem is that it is waiting for element for a long period of time and does not find. And error is not present. But when I try debug element is finding.
As you can see I use `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);` in every method. May be it is the problem.

**I have BasicClasses**

```
public class BasicClasses {
    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected LoginPage login;
    protected AccountsPage account;
    protected ContactPage contact;
    protected HomePage home;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(Url.loginUrl);
        login = new LoginPage(driver);
        home = new HomePage(driver);
        login.loginAs(Data.usernameLogin, Data.passwordLogin).chooseDealerFromDealerPopUP();
        home.checkIfAccountForTestingIsPresent();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {

        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }
```

**Login Page:**

```
public class LoginPage extends Page {
    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public  HomePage loginAs(String user, String pass) throws InterruptedException{

            assertEquals("Sign In", driver.findElement(By.xpath(Locator.headerForm)).getText());
            driver.findElement(By.id(Locator.usernameLocatorLogin)).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id(Locator.usernameLocatorLogin)).sendKeys(user);
            driver.findElement(By.id(Locator.passwordLocatorLogin)).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id(Locator.passwordLocatorLogin)).sendKeys(pass);
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(Locator.submitButtonLoginPage)).click();

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(Locator.selectDealerPopUp)));

            return new HomePage(driver);
    }
```

**Abstact class Page:**

```
public abstract class Page {

    protected WebDriver driver;

    public Page(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;

    }

    public WebDriver getWebDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
```

**And test:**

```
public class AddContactAT extends BasicClasses {

    @Test
    public void testAddContactWithNoAccess() throws Exception {

        contact.addContactWithFullAccess("sss");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the element is really visible, and there is no other element on  top of it? Or that the element is not stale?

Comment: Yes, the element is one on the page. But page use ajax. And in the //div[@style='display: block;']//h4[@class='modal-title' and contains(text(), 'Please select a Dealer')]
display: block; become display: none;

Comment: When the page uses Ajax, you could try to add a sendKeys(Keys.TAB) to every field that you fill using sendKeys. Then the AJAX on that field is performed. Maybe it helps. but no guarantee....

Comment: Do you think that the code and using page object is correct?

Comment: Could be. I don't know... (I don't know the rest of your code or the webpage :)) Your debug could just add enough time to display the element...

Comment: Thanks. The problem was in Ajax. I fixed it. Can somebody give comments about my pageobject :) Thanks a lot

Comment: I would suggest to use presenceOfElementLocated in the ExpectedConditions instead yours visibilityOfElementLocated

Comment: If test is passing while debugging, then your wait time seems lower than required. Did you try increasing the wait timeout?

Comment: My problem was fixed by using such xpath
//div[not(contains(@style, 'display: none;'))]//h4[contains(@class, 'modal-title') and contains(text(), 'Please select a Dealer')]